# Limits of The Force

Tags: star-wars, the-force

What are the limits of the Force?

In geometrical terms how far can the force act?  As i have only watched the movies,  there is ambiguities in it..  For eg.  Leia can feel the force then why she didn't when Luke was dying in the cold in the initial part of The Empire Strikes Back?

And in other terms like can it only be used for communication,  and moving things or it has more to it?

Comment: Please delete it ASAP as there is no option to delete it in the Android app and i don't want any negative votes ONLY IF ITS DUPLICATE... I give full permission to do that

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/51883/4918 "Long-distance Mind Trick"

Comment: [We don't delete questions just for being duplicates.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7943/31394) Duplicates are useful, as they increase searchability for the original question.